# How to fix screen tearing with nvidia?

Tags: display

I tried various fixes such as using forcecompositionpipeline = on (edited /etc/x11/xorg.conf, there was no option for it in the nvidia x settings) but still the issue persists. Switching to intel graphics with the option "TearFree" "true" fixes it, but is there a way to fix it without switching? I need to work with nvidia graphics.

Yes, I have updated to the latest drivers (390.12) and I have a gt 940m. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed it! Followed the instructions in [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/6z99n7/fix_for_screen_tearing_on_nividia_optimus_prime/). Apparently, the solution isn't popular. Works like a charm!

Comment: This didn't work for me :/ I have a GeForce GTX 1050, nvidia 387 driver

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia drivers should also come with a settings application to tweak your graphic card and its settings. You may find an option in those settings to enable VSync or Sync To VBlank. I don't know of any settings in elementary settings themselves to control this unfortunately.